# VB Log WebBrowser Status

Tags: vb.net, browser, status

i'm working on a new project and I'm currently stuck. I'm adding a logger using a ListBox.

In my project I'm using a WebBrowser and I want to add to the log every time the page has loaded. And i'm trying to do it like this:

```
    If WebBrowser1.StatusText.ToString = "Klar" Then
        Label14.Text = "Success"
    End If
    If Label14.Text = "Success" Then
        Logger.Items.Add("> Successfully loaded")
    End If
```

"Klar" translates to "Done" (Swedish)

But the status updates all the time and spam "Done/Klar" so my item to the logger adds 5+ times befor the status changes (I change the page).

So I'm looking for some way to only write it once, maybe check if it already has been added on the item befor. I'm using this in a timer so it will be added many times in the log, but I only want it to be added once if the last item in the log is the same.

Anyone know how this is done?

Thanks for your help!
PS. I will take a look at this thread in the morning, But I would really appreciate any help I can get :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked up an example for you and very easy to follow. Just change what you need to. You can use the "Contains Function" to get what you need to check if the item exists in your listbox control.

```
    Public Class Form1

'Global Variable to hold your string(text)'
Private strText As String = ""

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim myArray() As String = {"Car", "Truck", "Motorcycle"}
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(myArray)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'First whatever you are sending to the listbox you need to set it to a variable'
    'For example I want to see if Motorcycle exists in the listbox so I set my variable'
    strText = "Motorcycle"

    'Now lets check if this exists in our listbox!'
    If ListBox1.Items.Contains(strText) Then
        'We can even select the item that is found'
        ListBox1.SelectedItem = strText

        MsgBox("Listbox contains: " & strText) 'Or do what you want here'

    Else
        MsgBox("NO FOUND ITEM")
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

You can ignore the load as I used this just for testing... Also just put this code where you have it inserting your data (before it does the insert into your listbox and if its not in the listbox, continue to add what you want to. Let me know how it works out for you!

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your solution really helped.
All tho the Contains function will tell me if the variable(strText) exists in my Listbox.
And I want to add the variable more then one time. But just once every time.
But thanks to your way I saw things differently and were able to find the sulotion that fits my needs. I will add how I ended up as an answer. (I hope thats ringt, Im new here)

Thanks for taking the time to help me out! :)

Comment: Your Welcome, please check as answered if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The container functions didnt really fit for what I wanted. I wanted to be able to add the same variable/item/string more then one time and still be able to only add it once in the row in the logger.

So because I'm using this as a logger I want it to auto select a new item because I want it to "follow" the newsest item.

So I checked if the selected item equals my variable is false. Then I added the variable to my logger/listbox.

```
SuccessLoad = "> Successfully loaded"

    If WebBrowser1.StatusText.ToString = "Done" Then
        If Logger.SelectedItem.Equals(SuccessLoad) = False Then 'adds if not selected
            Logger.Items.Add(SuccessLoad)
            Logger.SelectedIndex = Logger.Items.Count - 1 'selects the variable
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: I answered your problem for what you requested to have answered and it does what you need it to do.. You said you only wanted it added once.. What do you mean by adding the variable more than once, but only adding it once to your listbox, that doesn't make much sense unless you clarify a bit more. If you need other help other than this ask another question so others can help you... Thanks!~

Comment: Ye, I can understand the confusion.. I didnt explain it so good. Well, I'm building a logger to my program which will add strings/variable to the log. So I could easy see what actually happends. So lets say im using this to spam visitors on a site(Im not) I press Start and then everytime the page loads I want it to add to the log that it is done then StatusText = "Done". And this item will be added every 10 secounds if it's running. So bu checking if it already contains wouldnt work because I want it/know it already contains. I dont want it to be added more then once then it's added.

Comment: So what I did now will only work if I will add a new String/variable to the log befor 10 secounds then the "if statustext = "Done" variable/string will be added one more time. So my answer is still a "hotfix" to my problem. I could use the contains finstion but then I will have to do something like "if it contains less then 3 times" and then add + 1 to "3" every time I add the variable/string again. If you know a better way to do this I would be happy to see it :) Thanks for your help and time, really appreciate it! :)